# Run a single instance of a class in multiple methods

Tags: java

My class in concern is this:

```
public class Gscore
    private score;

    public void setscore(float a)
    {
        float Score=a;
    }

    public getscore()
    {
        return Score;
    }
```

In two separate java files, I would like to set a score in one file and access the set value in the other java file. Snippets from the two files are as follows:

**file 1**

```
Gscore scoregen= new Gscore();
scoregen.setscore(playerscore);
new file2;
```

**file 2**

```
Gscore scoregen= new Gscore();
System.out.print(scoregen.getresponse());
```

However, the results are always null, what am i doing wrong how do I get file 2 to display the value that I set in file 1.

Comment: Well you aren't setting the value silly.. try a call to the `setscore` method you made then use `getscore`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going with @3kings on this one.  Make sure that you set your value with the setscore function.  Unless you're just not showing that part of the code?  Also it's a bad practice to name a variable with a capital letter.

Comment: well i want the player score that's been set in file one to be what is shown in file 2

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is you are not using the same instance of the class in both the methods. You are instantiating the class GScore twice. Just having the same reference variable name does not amount to same instance.

Once you have the instance instantiated, pass the same object reference to the second method. You should be able to get the results which is not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

For a start

```
Public void setscore(int a)
{
Float Score=a;  // this is a problem as this is local scope
}
```

Secondly, to use the same Object then you should instantiate it just once and then pass it to your other class.

Another possibility is to use a Singleton class http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm